# Как запускать функцию каждые 20 секунд

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Существует функция:

```
def hi()
    print ("Hi")
hi()
```

Как заставить ее запускаться через каждые 20 секунд?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так, но будет длится бесконечно.

```
import time
while True:
    hi()
    time.sleep(20)
```